# Unable to set & get variable value in find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs

I am trying to use `template_subject` variable as a `subject` for email sending.

When I extract data from mongodb by using `findOne` & set the variable `template_subject`. It just gives me value `undefined`.

I have tested it from all sides, data comes perfectly from back end, just it is not been set to `variable`.

Anybody have some solution for this?

```
exports.sendMailMsg = function (templateName, email) {

var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var template_subject;
var template_html;    

Template.findOne({name: templateName}, function (err, template) {      
    template_subject = template.subject;
    template_html = template.dataMsg;
});

//----- Email Options -----//
var mailOptions = {
    from: "Xyz <foo@blurdybloop.com>", // sender address
    to: email, // list of receivers
    subject: template_subject, // Subject line
    html: "<b>Hello,</b><br/><br/> You are successfuly Registered"
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because findOne function is asynchronous, so by the time the result is fetched, the mailOptions variable is already defined.
So maybe you could do this:

```
exports.sendMailMsg = function (templateName, email) {

var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var template_subject;
var template_html;    

Template.findOne({name: templateName}, function (err, template) {      
    template_subject = template.subject;
    template_html = template.dataMsg;

    //----- Email Options -----//
    var mailOptions = {
        from: "Xyz <foo@blurdybloop.com>", // sender address
        to: email, // list of receivers
        subject: template_subject, // Subject line
        html: "<b>Hello,</b><br/><br/> You are successfuly Registered"
    };

    //Do all the processing here...
});
```